# Not getting all products in opencart module

Tags: module, opencart

I am developing an Opencart Module to show all products with type=Deal. While I have 3 products to test, it only shows 1 product. here is the code.

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();
foreach ($results as $result) {

     if($result['type'] == "Deal"){
           $this->data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
            'thumb'      => $image,
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            //'company'      => $result['company'],
            'redurl'         => $result['redurl'],
            'coupon'         => $result['coupon'],
        );
            }
 }
```

Comment: Please `print_r($results);` and update the question.

Comment: print_r($results) shows all products

Comment: Among those products can you count 3 products with `type` - "Deal" ?

Comment: Sure all 3 including all products are there, in fact array of 42 comes

Comment: basically it gets only first matched product

Comment: do the `print_r(products)` in tpl file see how many product it gives

Comment: it returns only 1 product

Comment: that's weird. you are probably doing something wrong in the rest of the code. paste your complete controller & view file on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: You should be selecting the products of type deal directly from the database only - in that case You'd receive only those three products from DB and You would not need to loop them through - **saving a lot of processor time and resources**! E.g. call the `getProducts(array('type' => 'Deal'))` while changing the model's method a little letting You to specify the product type directly in the query...

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the model section.

module > product

check function getProducts();

modify sql query place with WHERE conditions.